# WHY is wifi enabled then disabled on boot? How can I have it enabled (Pi + 20.04.1)

Tags: boot, wireless, raspberrypi, rfkill

I installed 20.04 on a Raspberry Pi - just the server version.  I then subsequently installed the minimal desktop.

I would like my wifi to be enabled on boot up, and have tried a few methods, but just can't get it working.

I've tried:

- editing /var/lib/systemd/rfkill/platform-fe300000.mmcnr:wlan (0|1)
- editing /boot/firmware/usercfg.txt (rfkill.default_state=0|1)
- adding a service late on to issue 'rfkill unblock all' disabling systemctl
- disable systemd-rfkill, .service and .socket, but they both are
  enabled on the next boot

I've looked through the systemd startup logs and have seen that wifi is enabled then disabled.

nmcli gives:

```
wlan0: unavailable
        "Broadcom BCM43438 combo and Bluetooth Low Energy"
        wifi (brcmfmac), DC:A6:32:43:6D:27, sw disabled, hw, mtu 1500
```

rfkill gives:

```
ID TYPE DEVICE    SOFT      HARD
 0 wlan phy0   blocked unblocked
```

**Why are there competing processes independently trying to control the wifi adapter???**

I know I could possibly hack a service together that sleeps for a period of time before issuing the 'rfkill unblock all' command, but I would like to do this properly, so can someone please enlighten me on which processes I need to look at (enable, disable, configure, uninstall)?

It's a Raspberry Pi so I'm assuming the driver issues causing the rfkill softblock are not the cause as rfkill works immediately on the command line.  In fact, even when I run `rfkill unblock all` and wifi is up, nmcli returns:

```
wlan0: unavailable
        "Broadcom BCM43438 combo and Bluetooth Low Energy"
        wifi (brcmfmac), DC:A6:32:43:6D:27, sw disabled, hw, mtu 1500
```

I don't mind doing the reading, but can someone please tell me where to start?

Thanks in advance,

Jason

Comment: Ubuntu server ships with Netplan and systemd-networkd. networkd and NetworkManager try to do the same job on the same device (which is why the Pi instructions tell you how to get WiFi working using Netplan instead of NM). Seems like you may have created a conflict, trying to run both at once. Did you change your Netplan file to point to NM instead of networkd?

Comment: Post results for `dmesg | grep brcm`

Comment: You have a SDIO device and it likely needs firmware not included, post results for `dmesg | grep brcm`

Comment: Output is too big for a comment - https://pastebin.com/iu87vPk2

Comment: Thanks @user535733, I'll look into that now...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @user535733, this is now fixed!

The solution was to specify

```
    renderer: networkd
```

in `/etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml`

It appears that NetworkManager and systemd-networkd *were* competing, so I stopped and disabled NetworkManager

```
sudo systemctl stop NetworkManager
sudo systemctl disable NetworkManager
sudo reboot
```

On the subsequent boot and the 3 since, wlan0 is all present and correct.